# How to rewrite code from array to arraylist without using .asList?

Tags: java

Teacher gave this code and said to rewrite it so that there is no array and just rewritten to arraylist. I am not allowed to use .asList. Any idea how to do this?

```
public APCSStudents(Student[] sarray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < sarray.length; i++)
        studentarray[i] = sarray[i];
}

public Student bestStudent() {
    Student s = studentarray[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < studentarray.length; i++){
        if (studentarray[i].getPoints() > s.getPoints()) {
            s = studentarray[i];
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Please clean up your code format.  Indent code 4 spaces to get the proper formatting, and indent everything using spaces, not tabs.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a homework help site. We aren't going to write your code for you. Please visit the [help] and read [ask]

Comment: I am sorry. First time here

Comment: I can give you a hint tho, you use your array to create an instance, access its size and access a single element. If you find out how to do this operations with an ArrayList you can just substituite the two containers.

Comment: @bracco23 I am assuming you mean this right:                              Element[] array = {new Element(1), new Element(2)};
List<element> list = new ArrayList<element>(array.length);
Collections.addAll(list, array);                                                                           Yeah I can't use this either. I tried doing other things to but I just can't get it. I feel like there is simply solution...

Comment: No i mean that in the end array or lists are just a collection of elements. In your code all you do is creating an array, looking for his size and accessing a certain element. If you know how to do those things with a list, you can just use one in the place of the other. It's simpler than you think

Comment: I think your teacher meant rewrite it so that you aren't using arrays -- in other words, `.asList` doesn't mean anything. Rewrite the code so that, from the ground up, it uses `ArrayList` instead of arrays.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Thanks this was probably why I couldn't do it since I though the question was literally asking to convert array to arrayList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hints, equivalences:

```
Student[] studentsArray = new Student(100);
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

studentsArray.length;
students.size();
// See also students.isEmpty()

s = studentsArray[i];
s = students.get(i);

studentsArray[i] = s;
students.set(i, s);

students.add(s); // Adding to a growing array
```

The Javadoc of [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) may prove interesting.

Comment: Oh my. Ok it seems like I misinterpreted the question. The question was actually asking to rewrite the code not using array and just use arrayList. Ok, thanks for this anways, I think I know how to do now.